# Regex character set (e.g. [[:word:]]) and backslash construct (e.g. \sw): is there preference of one over the other?

Tags: regex, emacs

I am reading the regex chapter [char set](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html#Regexps) and [backslash constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html#Regexp-Backslash).

It appears to an untutored eye that the two functions quite similarly in terms of matching a set of characters.

For example, a `[[:word:]]` and a `\sw` both match to all word-constituent characters, as I thought.

1. May I know whether there is any situation that one is preferred over
   the other? Just for a better understanding.

   Or, maybe another way of asking this is: what is the difference
   between *character class* (e.g. `[:word:]`) and *syntax class*(e.g.`w`)?
2. Is *character class* the same thing as a *Category* [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Categories.html#Categories)?

   If yes, then I think the answer to question 1 might be obvious, since the manual says one major difference between a category and a syntax class is that the former no need to be mutually exclusive.(one char can belong to many categories.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything about syntax classes is just syntactic sugar of regular expressions algebra.

`[[:class:]]` is POSIX regular expression syntax. You can study the details by pressing <kbd>M-x man RET 7 regex RET</kbd>. These classes refer to only 1 character that is chosen from a set. Emacs is posix-compatible, and implemented this syntax. These classes are a high-level concepts obtained from atomic characters and the `OR` operator from algebra. Example: the class `digit` is defined as `0` or `1` or ... or `9`, and consequently [:digit:] refers to only 1 character from this set.

In regular expression algebra the atomic structures are the characters, and there are 3 operators: OR, KLEENE STAR, and CONCAT. All the other things are combinations of these -- abstractions like `+ = [class][class]*` or new concepts like WORD are obtained by combinations of these.

However, when you program, you need to use high level patterns, which are built over these classes, like WORD=[a-zA-Z0-9]+. This is so common, that the programmers created a special name for them. WORD is a combination of atomic structures, namely  `[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]]*`. Note that this involves the basic class alnum and a `concatenation` operator and `kleene star` operator. So, WORD is a concept obtained by making combinations of basic operators and atomic concepts (`alnum` is not atomic, because it can be defined at its turn via the `char` and the `or` operator, as stated above).

To answer your 2nd question, categories in emacs are the inverse operations. If WORD=[a-z...], you sometimes want to know, given a charater, if it belongs to WORD, or what other class it was defined in.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It involves many concepts that are new to me, which I am trying to further understand them.

Comment: you can start by reading the mathematical definitions of regexps, to see what's essential there.